# I want to count and analysis crashes only in my SDK(framework),but not occur in APP which integrated my SDK

Tags: ios, sdk, crash

I am a SDK developer and now i want to collect **crashes only in my SDK**.But when a crash occur, it may be caused by the app which integrated my SDK.What i what to do is filter those.

The first thing i thought of was integrate third party library like KSCrash.But the problem is that the KSCrash is init in AppDelegate.m and effective all APP life include SDK.So i do not know **how to integrate it only in my SDK**???

ths for anybody who can help me

Answer (score 0):

This would be fairly difficult to achieve, as crashes occur at the process level rather than your framework having its own isolated 'section' or subprocess.

You can do some workaround to filter your SDK crash log, using below code block you can capture the crash log in your SDK.

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application finishedLaunchingWithOptions (NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
    }

    void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
    //get the log from exception
    }
```

and then you have to register this ExceptionHandler from application AppDelegate finishedLaunchingWithOptions using below code block

```
[YourSDK_Instance application:application finishedLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But the method you mentioned is belong to AppDelegate.m, and this file is belong to external APP which integrated my SDK. So, do I need to prompt external developer to write this part of code?  Is there a way for me to do the crash clollection inside my framework?

Comment: yes you have to ask app developer to call this from app delegate. as per my knowledge there is no way to capture crash log inside framework.

Comment: For the similar requirement i have implemented something like this in one of the sdks i have worked on.

Comment: yes I know your means.But if app developer had integrated other crash lib, how to being sure that there is no conflict between the other crash lib and my own cllect way? After all, both of they will  respond to the crash.

Comment: NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler will get called after each crash if it is registered from AppDelegate, to make sure the conflicts is not there you can create two sdk with  NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler and check.

Comment: is it convenient to discuss your idea to filter the app crash? My idea is based on the scope of the address of the crash stack, after linking method in app and in SDK belong to different address ranges.And I write a demo then proved it is no problem to distinguish two type of crash.

Comment: i think its convenient to filter the app crash, if you are comfortable with scope of the address of the crash stack then why not give it a try?

Comment: I know and I implemented it .I just want to discuss about your idea .if conveniently, is  it more better?

Comment: sorry chaors, i'm not sure about that.